# Inserting image into a file

Tags: html, image, odoo

I'm trying to insert one image with html and is not detecting it.
The path is in the same folder.

[Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uX3m.png)

The code is in the education_website_index_template.xml file.

```
<body id="layout_body">
 <header id="layout_header">
  <div class="container" id="layout_container">
   <div id="company_logo">
    <img src="coas.jpg" alt="Coas logo" />
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
```

Some one knows why the image is not showing.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkpvD.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you store the image you want to display?

Comment: You must set your address from base path (base url) of image, for example : `http://example.com/views/coas.jpg` or `/views/coas.jpg`

Comment: The image is stored in /views/coas.jpg and the file is stored in the same folder. @vargaadam

Comment: I tried to use the path from the root folder and the issue is still there. @ttrasn

Comment: @arevilla009 where is your main project url ?!

Comment: @arevilla009 Don't mix the URL and the server folder/directory structure: it's often very close, but it's not the same. `src` tag is relative to the URL. So manually go to `your/page/url/coas.jpg` and see if you get the image. I think you actually get a 404 or 500 because of a misconfiguration in your server. Otherwise, open your browser console (F12), reload the page, and see if you have error message (maybe a CSP issue)

Answer (score 0):

Tried this code :

```
 <img src="./views/coas.jpg" alt="Coas logo" />
```

Comment: Tried, the issue still there. Maibe any other file can conflict with this?

Answer (score 0):

if your code is "pure HTML", there are some syntax mismatches:

- the "header" part must appear first, and before the "body"
- Everything must be included in the "html"
- Check that you are consistent between the opening and closing tags

```
<html>
<header>
 <!-- nothing in your case.... -->

</header>
<body id="layout_body">
 <div id="layout_header">
   <div class="container" id="layout_container">
      <div id="company_logo">
         <img src="coas.jpg" alt="Coas logo" />
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```